# backbone.js view with jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I found few similar questions but none of them worked for me...
I have jquery plugin loaded with require.js (it's loading after view script) and I need to access its method on input change, I did try to do it in reder but it's the same. that's what I have so far.

```
events: {
    "change #signageUploadInput": "loadingImage"
},

loadingImage: function(event) {
    $('body').loadImage(
        event.target.files[0],
        function (img) {
            document.body.appendChild(img);
        },
        {maxWidth: 600}
    );
}
```

Object [object Object] has no method 'loadImage'

Comment: Deleted my answer. Failed to read you're using a plugin. Can I ask what plugin you're using?

Comment: I use this plugin https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image

Answer (score 1):

Turns out script IS accessible from backbone view. The problem was the way the plugin tried to access window object. I used different script and it worked well. That's what I used:

uploader.js

```
function my_uploader(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // Loop through the FileList and render image files as thumbnails.
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

        // Only process image files.
        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
            continue;
        }

        var reader = new FileReader();

        // Closure to capture the file information.
        reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
            return function(e) {
                // Render thumbnail.
                var span = document.createElement('span');
                span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                                  '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
                document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
            };
        })(f);

        // Read in the image file as a data URL.
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
    }
}
```

backbone view script

```
events: {
    "change #signageUploadInput": "loadImage",
},
loadImage: function(evt) {
    my_uploader(evt);   //script is inside fileuploader.js
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When is this error coming up, when you load the page or on your Backbone event firing? Because if it's when the page loads, Backbone might be trying to go through and compile all of your events and functions before require.js has loaded your plugin file. Need some more info to figure this out though, could you post the part where you are loading in the JavaScript file with require.js?

Comment: Error occurring in the right time :)  on input change, so it means it's reacting when I need it, but can't access plugin's code

Comment: Just looking through their API documentation, are you sure it's compatible with jQuery? It doesn't look like a jQuery plugin to me, simply an extension to the `window` object to load the image. And that would explain your `Object [object Object] has no method 'loadImage'` error as well, because if it were a plugin there would be no problem. Maybe try the same thing but using the same code as their API docs, so `window.loadImage()`.

Comment: it does the same for window.loadImage()